# Converter tamanho da imagem antes de salvar no BD

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, imagem, mysqli

Gostaria de incrementar meu código de processamento:

```
// Local onde imagem vai ser salva
$_UP['pasta'] = '../../media/';
// Tamanho da imagem
$_UP['tamanho'] = 1024*250; // 250Kb
// Exrensões permitidas
$_UP['extensoes'] = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif');
// Renomear a imagem
$_UP['renomear'] = false;

// Tipos de erro de UpLoad do PHP
$_UP['erros'][0] = 'Não houve erro';
$_UP['erros'][1] = 'Imagem maior que o limite do php';
$_UP['erros'][2] = 'Imagem muito grande';
$_UP['erros'][3] = 'UpLoad da imagem feita parcialmente';
$_UP['erros'][4] = 'Erro no UpLoad da imagem';

// Verifica se houve algum erro
if($_FILES['imagem']['erros'] != 0){
    die("Não foi possivel fazer UpLoad, Erro: <br />". $_UP['erros'][$_FILES['imagem']['erros']]);
exit;
}

// Verifica qual a extensão
$img_nome = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];
$img_separador = explode('.', $img_nome);
$extensao = strtolower(end($img_separador));
//$extensao = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['imagem']['name'])));
if(array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes'])=== false){
    echo "
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        alert(\"Arquivo não compatível: png, jpg, jpeg e gif. \");
    </script>
    ";
}
// Verifica o tamanho
else if ($_UP['tamanho'] < $_FILES['imagem']['size']){
    echo "Imagem muito grande, limite de 250Kb";
}
// Salva nos arquivos do site
else{
    //Verifica se deve trocar o nome da imagem
if($_UP['renomear'] == true){
    // Cria nome Baseado no UNIX TIMESTAMP atual e com extensão
    $nome_final = time().'.jpg';
}else{
    // Mantem o nome da imagem
    $nome_final = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];
}
// Verifica se é possivel mover a imagem para a pasta escolhida
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta'].$nome_final)){
    // Upload efetuado com sucesso
    $nome = $conectar->real_escape_string($nome);
    $desc = $conectar->real_escape_string($desc);
    $description = $conectar->real_escape_string($description);
    $tempo = $conectar->real_escape_string($tempo);
    $link = $conectar->real_escape_string($link);

    $query = mysqli_query($conectar, "INSERT INTO ...") or die(mysqli_error($conectar));
    $query_vist = mysqli_query($conectar, "INSERT INTO contador (nomePagina, visitas) VALUES ('".$1."', '".$quant."')") or die(mysqli_error($conectar));
    echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=#'>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert(\"Cadastrado com Sucesso.\");
</script>
";
}
```

Ele apenas verifica, tem alguma forma de converter a imagem enviada pelo usuário para 500x500px? Assim posso manter um padrão no projeto. Alguém poderia mostrar um exemplo de como implementar utilizando meu código?

Comment: Neste link tem varias opções  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645/resize-image-in-php

Answer (score -1):

Para trabalhar com imagens no PHP é mais fácil usar recursos externos, sugiro a utilização do [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) ou do [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), no GD é bem fácil fazer isso:

```
function resize_image($file, $w, $h, $crop=FALSE) {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
    $r = $width / $height;
    if ($crop) {
        if ($width > $height) {
            $width = ceil($width-($width*abs($r-$w/$h)));
        } else {
            $height = ceil($height-($height*abs($r-$w/$h)));
        }
        $newwidth = $w;
        $newheight = $h;
    } else {
        if ($w/$h > $r) {
            $newwidth = $h*$r;
            $newheight = $h;
        } else {
            $newheight = $w/$r;
            $newwidth = $w;
        }
    }
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    return $dst;
}
```

e a chamada do método:

```
$img = resize_image(‘/path/to/some/image.jpg’, 200, 200);
```

Lembrando que o GB também faz a compressão da imagem.

Comment: é por não entender que eu não uso ^^, vou procurar como incorporar seu exemplo ao código, desde já Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Você pode dar um exemplo de onde ficaria no meu código?